# Названия банков

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Всегда ли названия банков пишутся в кавычках? Я знаю, что *Внешэкономбанк* и *Сбербанк* не берутся в кавычки, но почему *Центробанк* не кавычится? Какие еще названия банков стоит брать в кавычки, а какие нет?

Answer (score 2):

1) Обычно кавычки используются **только для определенных тематических групп** имен, в частности для названий литературных произведений и различных печатных изданий: роман Пушкина «Евгений Онегин», газета «Московский комсомолец». При использовании кавычек имена собственные представляются в виде выделенной единицы,  в этом случае всё название (а не отдельные слова) имеет условный характер и не склоняется,  для сравнения: Ленинский проспект и станция «Ленинский проспект».

2) Названия банков **обычно пишутся без кавычек**:  Сбербанк России, Внешэкономбанк, Центральный банк Российской Федерации (Банк России, Центробанк), банк Авангард.

3) **При отсутствии родового слова** кавычки могут ставиться: проблемы у "Авангарда", но: проблемы у Сбербанка (нет кавычек, "банк" входит в название). Здесь выбор зависит от стиля и тематики текста.

3) **Кавычки используются в официальных названиях коммерческих банков**, в этом случае они  обозначают не условность названия, а границы между двумя тематическими наименованиями предприятия (по виду собственности  и по роду деятельности). 
ПАО «Сбербанк России»,  ПАО «Акционерный Коммерческий банк «Авангард» .

**Следует учитывать статус банка:**

Центральный банк Российской Федерации (Банк России) — главный банк первого уровня, главный эмиссионный, денежно-кредитный институт Российской Федерации.

Внешэкономбанк не является коммерческим банком, его деятельность регулируется специальным законом №82-ФЗ "О банке развития".

Для этих банков не указывается вид собственности, они не являются коммерческими.

Answer (score 1):

КАВЫЧКАМИ выделяются:

Названия предприятий, фирм, бирж, ***банков,*** компаний, товариществ, кооперативов, общественных организаций, средств массовой информации, гостиниц, театров и т. д. (как в русском, так и в иноязычном вариантах названий): концерн "Газпром", банк "Менатеп", кооператив "Этна", издательство "Просвещение", спортивное общество "Динамо", фирма "Сони", концерн "Дженерал моторс корпорейшн", телевизионная компания "Коламбия бродкастинг систем" (Си-би-эс).

> См.: Культура устной и письменной речи делового человека: Справочник. Практикум. - 4-е изд.-М.:Флинта:Наука,2000.
>   Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В.,Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию.
>   Издание четвертое, исправленное.- М.: "ЧеРо", 2001
>
> P.S. Надо учитывать не статус банка, а вид наименования, представляющий название банка.

***Составные названия, не являющиеся условными – реальные собственные имена.***
В таких названиях все слова употребляются в прямом значении. Кавычками такие названия не выделяются; в них пишется с прописной буквы первое слово и входящие в состав наименования имена собственные.

ПРИМЕР: Государственный Русский музей, Московский драматический театр на Малой Бронной, Книга рекордов Гиннесса, Великая Отечественная война.
Условные (символические) названия, заключаемые в кавычки.
Реальные собственные имена и условные наименования различаются прежде всего синтаксической сочетаемостью:

> Условные (символические) названия, заключаемые в кавычки.
>   Реальные собственные имена и условные наименования различаются прежде всего синтаксической сочетаемостью:
>
> реальные собственные имена, в них присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, кавычки не нужны
>
> ***ПРИМЕР:Большой театр, Театр сатиры, Театр на Юго-Западе, Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации.***
>
> условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом. Они заключаются в кавычки.

ПРИМЕР: театр «Современник», театр «Школа современной пьесы», партия «Яблоко».

Реальные собственные имена тоже могут употребляться в сочетании с родовым наименованием (чаще всего – обозначением организационно-правовой формы) и при этом заключаться в кавычки, но при употреблении без родового наименования они, в отличие от условных названий, пишутся без кавычек.

ПРИМЕР: Московская типография № 2 и ОАО «Московская типография № 2», Город воинской славы и почетное звание «Город воинской славы»

В отличие от них условные названия заключаются в кавычки как при наличии родового слова, так и при его отсутствии.

ПРИМЕР: «Локомотив» и футбольный клуб «Локомотив», «Ромашка» и ООО «Ромашка»
Семантику названия учитывают при сложносокращенных словах.

Употребление кавычек при сложносокращенных словах зависит в первую очередь от семантики названия. Не заключаются в кавычки названия государственных учреждений, в их числе:

неофициальные наименования органов законодательной и исполнительной власти (министерств, федеральных агентств, федеральных служб, комитетов и др.)

> ПРИМЕР: Госдума, Мосгордума, Рособрнадзор, Центризбирком, Минэкономразвития.

наименования государственных учреждений, выступающие без родового слова. Однако при употреблении с родовым словом кавычки ставятся.

> ПРИМЕР: Мосгортранс, Мосводоканал, но ГУП «Мосгортранс», МГУП «Мосводоканал»

В отличие от названий госучреждений, сложносокращенные названия коммерческих организаций пишутся в кавычках (и при наличии родового слова, и при его отсутствии)

> ПРИМЕР: «Росгосстрах» и компания «Росгосстрах», «Технопромэкспорт» и ОАО «Технопромэкспорт», «Строймонтаж» и ЗАО «Строймонтаж».

ледует отметить, что некоторые названия крупнейших компаний, например Газпром, АвтоВАЗ и др., испытывают колебания в написании при употреблении без родового слова; при наличии родового слова постановка кавычек не вызывает сомнений: ОАО «Газпром», ОАО «АвтоВАЗ».

> ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: Без кавычек пишется название ***Сбербанк России.*** Этот пример можно считать уникальным: отсутствие кавычек при данном наименовании объясняется как историей его употребления, так и экстралингвистическими причинами. Несмотря на то что Сбербанк России в настоящее время является коммерческой организацией, у многих носителей языка он по-прежнему ассоциируется с госучреждением (в Сбербанке можно получить пенсию, оплатить коммунальные услуги и т. п.).

Comment: Серж, если взять список банков России, то там названия указаны без кавычек, это можно считать основной формой. Вы можете назвать банк, который пишется с кавычками? Если появляется указание формы собственности, то пишутся кавычки, поэтому ничего уникального в Сбербанке нет: ПАО «Сбербанк России».  Здесь сказывается тематика организации: банки пишут без кавычек, а «Строймонтаж» с кавычками, которые позволяют не склонять название, рассматривать его как единое целое. Поэтому надо понимать роль кавычек в написании конкретного названия.

Comment: банк «Менатеп» ( из справочника Розенталя). Вера, повторюсь. Если название банка условное название кавычки ставятся, если реальное наименование(без родового слова) - без кавычек.

Comment: Устаревшая  запись, например, есть Торговый дом «Менатеп» и есть банк Менатеп. Приходится ориентироваться на практику письма.  И обратим внимание: если нет родового слова, то кавычки ставятся, а почему? (Деятельность «Менатепа» позволяет нам уверенно смотреть в завтрашний день). Потому что без родового слова непонятно, о чем идет речь. Сравнить: деятельность Сбербанка, здесь "банк" входит в основу названия, уже не ошибешься.

Comment: Вера, не совсем ясно, на основании чего Вы делаете выводы о устаревшей записи. В случае с "Менатепом'' - условное наименование.  По поводу ***Сбербанка*** уже говорилось в моем ответе.  Все зависит от вида названия. указанная Вами семантика действительна только сложносокращенных наименований.

Comment: Вот список банков, кавычек нет нигде, кроме исключений: http://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/ Исключение: Банк «Санкт-Петербург», чтобы с городом не спутать.

Comment: Вера, Вы приводите список, логично, что нет кавычек. А вы посмотрите употребление в текстах в СМИ.

Comment: Нет нормальных правил, вот и нет грамотного письма.  Здесь нужно учитывать разные факторы: наличие родового слова, вид текста, стиль текста, наличие слова или основы "банк" в названии, известность названия. А у нас один вопрос: ставить или не ставить кавычки, как правильно? А одного ответа нет, и в то же время не должно быть произвольного решения: поставил кавычки - значит, объясни почему.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагала, наоборот, названия банков в основном пишутся в кавычках за исключением нескольких случаев... Справочная группа Грамоты.ру не раз на это указывала.

Comment: Но ведь можно зайти на официальный сайт банка, посмотреть, как пишется его название в различных текстах. Указания  Грамоты.ру не всегда совпадают с практикой написания слова.

Comment: Практика написания не всегда совпадает с грамматическими правилами, мне бы хотелось получить четкую рекомендацию с лингвистической точки зрения.

Comment: Указание Грамоты.ру основываются на правилах. Какую рекомендацию вы еще хотите получить?

Comment: Если название название банка условное название кавычки ставятся, если реальное наименование(без родового слова) - без кавычек. Это и есть рекомендация.

Comment: Если мы имеем дело со сложившейся системой практического письма, то мы должны объяснить его, а как это сделать? Теории на тему  постановки кавычек Вы вряд ли найдете, лингвисты не очень жалуют практическую орфографию, им интереснее заниматься отвлеченными идеями. Тогда приходится на основе существующей практики письма делать определенные теоретические выводы и проверять их правильность опять же на практике. Это обычный путь получения знаний, если эта тема еще не проработана должным образом.

Comment: Но самое интересное заключается в том, что общество не чувствует потребности в таких знаниях, поэтому никто и ничего прорабатывать и объяснять не будет.

Comment: Серж, на Грамоте я читала, что ВСЕ названия банков кавычатся, КРОМЕ Сбербанка и Внешэкономбанка. В исключениях не было Центробанка. Правильно ли я понимаю, что к реальным наименованиям вы относите названия типа Банк Москвы, Россельхозбанк, Рост Банк - то есть, родовое слово входит в название? А такие названия, как "Возрождение, банк "Пересвет" мы кавычим?